# Why is a branch is present in section "local ref configured for git push" but absent in section "local branch configured for git pull"

Tags: git, version-control, push, pull

I'm currently learning git by following the book "progit 2nd edi".

In the section "inspecting a remote", the author had the following example.

[image]

I have noticed that the "markdown-strip" branch is absent in the section "local branch configured for git pull" but present in section "local ref configured for git push". I was wondering why this is the case.

PS: I understand how "git pull" and "git push" works. It is the absence of "markdown-strip" branch in "local branch configured for git pull" that's puzzling me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a synthetic example, so it *could* just be a mistake. However, it could also be a side effect of a particular configuration, where local branch `markdown-strip` has no upstream set.

Remember, the *upstream* of any branch is a two-part setting that you can set with one command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<upstream> <branch>
```

such as:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

or configure rather clumsily with a two separate `git config` commands:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Every branch name, such as `master`, can have *one* upstream set, or it can have *no* upstream set.  (That is, you cannot set two or more upstreams.  You *can* set one `remote` and two or more `merge`s, and `git show` does something special with them; but this is not a normal configuration, and `git branch --set-upstream-to` cannot and will not do this.)

To remove the upstream the normal way, use `git branch --unset-upstream`.  Below, I do it an abnormal way, although the effect on `git remote show origin` is the same either way.  (I deleted one of the two settings in my editor, because that lets me undo the delete in the editor, which is easier than typing in a `git branch` command.  Of course I have now taken much more time explaining this than just doing it the normal way. :-) )

The upstream for any local branch can be another local branch, but more typically it's what Git calls a *remote-tracking branch.*<sup>1</sup>  You don't normally want or need to *un-set* an upstream.  You do sometimes want to *set* an upstream, but if you use the normal method, you cannot set the upstream for a new branch until you have first *pushed* that new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b newbr
... the usual stuff here ...
$ git commit
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/newbr
```

This complains and fails, because `origin/newbr` does not exist yet, because we created `newbr` locally but have not yet pushed it to `origin`, so there *is* no `origin/newbr` in our repository.  Once we *do* run `git push origin newbr`, that creates `newbr` on origin.  That in turns creates our own `origin/newbr` to remember the `newbr` we just created on origin, and—whew!—now we can finally set `origin/newbr` as the upstream for `newbr`.

I think in this case the Pro Git authors had a repository where they created a branch locally, then pushed it to remote named `origin`, but never got around to running `git branch --set-upstream-to` on the branch.

#### An example

For instance, my copy of the Git repo for Git has local branch `master` configured with its upstream set to `origin/master`.  If I run `git remote show origin` I get (after the usual earlier output):

```
  Remote branches:
    maint  tracked
    master tracked
    next   tracked
    pu     tracked
    todo   tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master    merges with remote master
    stash-exp merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

(`stash-exp` is where I put a bug fix for `git stash` ages ago).  If I *delete* the line `merge = refs/heads/master` from `.git/config` and run `git remote show origin` again, I get this:

```
  Remote branches:
    maint  tracked
    master tracked
    next   tracked
    pu     tracked
    todo   tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    stash-exp merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Note that this still claims `master pushes to master`.  In fact, *nothing* pushes to *anything* as the `origin` repository is read-only.

This claim is just about what Git would *attempt*, were I to run `git push origin master`.  In this case my Git would call up their Git and discover that we both have a branch named `master`.  My Git would then suggest to their Git that they should set *their* `refs/heads/master` to point to the same commit as *my* `refs/heads/master`.  They would refuse—their repository is set to reject such an attempt—but my Git doesn't know that.

When I removed the `branch.master.merge = refs/heads/master` setting, my Git stopped saying `master    merges with remote master`.  As soon as I put that setting back, my Git starts saying it again.  This does not mean that my `master` *always* merges with their `master`: it just means that if I were to run `git pull`, and their `master` had new commits, my Git would, as its second step for `git pull`, run `git merge origin/master` (more or less).  The `git pull` command uses the upstream setting to determine what to do.  But I never<sup>2</sup> run `git pull`, because `git pull` is a terrible tool.

(I always `git fetch` first, then generally inspect things, then run `git rebase` if appropriate, or use my `git mff` alias, which is short for `git merge --fast-forward`.  Note that `git rebase` and `git merge` *also* use the upstream setting.  So does `git status`, for that matter—so it's quite useful to set the upstream, even if you avoid `git pull`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember, a so-called *remote-tracking branch* like `origin/master` is (a) in *your* repository (it's not remote at all, it's local); and (b) is just your Git's way of remembering what your Git saw on `origin` for `origin`'s `master` the last time your Git called up `origin`'s Git.  You cannot get "on" `origin/master` the way `git checkout master` gets you on your own `origin` branch, which means that (c) a remote-tracking branch is not even a branch!  So a remote-tracking branch (1) isn't remote, (2) does remember what your Git saw on another Git, and (3) isn't a branch.  Only one of the three words, *tracking*, in its name is halfway correct! :-)

The hyphenated form, *remote-tracking*, makes this better, because it's a thing that "tracks a branch as seen on a remote".  The whole thing then makes a sort of sense, but the name starts out very misleading.  People think that a *remote-tracking branch* is like a local branch, and it isn't.  But that's not the worst problem: they used to be called *remote branches*, and some people still use that phrase.  In any case, both these local names and these remote-tracking names are just *names*; the branch itself is yet another entity.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>[What, never?  Well, hardly ever!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c548RjB8jzQ)

Comment: hi torek, thanks for the detailed answer! its far better than what I would have hoped for! really appreciate you taking the time helping out!